# Is room capable of getting data from dataclasses?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

this might be a basic question but I cannot find any way to do it and I am not even sure whether that it is possible:
let's say I have a data class named "LoginCredentials", which takes 2 values: username and password (both strings)
could I make a query that looks like that?:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM X WHERE username = :loginCredentials.username AND password = :loginCredentials.password")
```

or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Did you try this? Or do you have any issues with this one? @Query("SELECT * FROM X WHERE username = ${loginCredentials.username} AND password = ${loginCredentials.password}")

Comment: "Room only supports named bind parameter :name to avoid any confusion between the method parameters and the query bind parameters." - this would suggest not.  As for the above suggestion that won't work as Room uses patten matching on the query for syntax highlighting and linting (plus its a java library), it won't recognise koltin string interpolation.  SqlDelight has better functionality for this IMO, but thats a design decision outside scope of your question.

Comment: @sfmirtalebi I already tried that, does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible - I'm not a *Room* expert, but the documentation only mentions [referencing parameters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#simple-parameters) and [expanding collections](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#collection-parameters) in a `@Query` string. There's nothing about using more complex, arbitary data structures.

I think the way you're meant to do it is with a public method in your DAO that takes your data structure, and have that internally call another function that takes the individual parameters:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM X WHERE username = :username AND password = :password")
    fun getFromUserAndPass(username: String, password: String): Whatever

    fun getFromLoginCreds(creds: LoginCredentials) =
        getFromUserAndPass(creds.username, creds.password)

}
```

There's no way to make that "internal" version private that I know of (adding it to an `interface` disallows that, not sure if there's an alternative) but you can always abstract access to your DAO through a repository layer or something, with its own API

Comment: 1. The dao you provided is really nice, I think I will use it
2. I looked around for similar code fragments and found [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pavan520/287659cfbe39c00af52c2f41ad351bf8/raw/a2db8cdf5e58cc42ea4da0da07a3435c8689d5fa/PersonalDataDao.kt), which is a part of [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-detailed-guide-on-room-database-with-kotlin-rx-mvvm-ea982e9c5abe) and it uses ${} inside a query and supposedly works? Are there any chances it might've changed over the years?

Comment: @JustSightseeing I mean if you see a thing you can always try it! But no, I think what's happening there is `PersonData.TABLE_NAME` is a *constant*, a way to define the name of the table in one place so you can reference it when you create the table, or define some queries - avoids errors like typos or forgetting to update everything if the name changes, y'know? *Room* takes that DAO interface and the query annotations and *generates code from them* at compile time, so it's just pulling the table name to finalise that query string. It's not referencing any runtime parameters from the function

Comment: you live and you learn I guess, thanks :D